# Não é preferível "Alô, Mundo" do que o "Olá, Mundo" que aparece nos anúncios do site em Português?

Tags: debate, stackexchange

Ainda não tenho reputação para enviar uma pergunta para o Meta, que é onde acho que esta pergunta deveria estar, mas desde a primeira vez que vi o "Olá, Mundo." eu achei estranho.

Talvez esta seja a forma usada em Portugal, e então nesse caso o site poderia ter dois anúncios diferentes conforme a região.

Comment: "Alô mundo" parece bem estranho em pt_PT

Comment: Acho que você está confundindo as coisas. Quando você cumprimenta alguém em inglês, você geralmente diz **hello** ou **hi**, sendo que **hello** significaria **Olá** e **hi** significaria **oi**, afinal você não diria **Alô** quando fosse cumprimentar alguém aqui no Brasil, diria?

Comment: Alô, Constantino. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Pelo que pesquisei, ambas as formas são semanticamente equivalentes. Entretanto, parece que "Olá, Mundo" soa mais idiomático aqui no Brasil e, pelo comentário do Jorge, o mesmo se aplica à Portugal. Sinta-se à vontade para perguntar, responder e dar qualquer outra sugestão para o site. Os votos positivos ou negativos aqui no Meta representam a opinião dos usuários sobre este assunto específico, mas a comunidade está aberta à participação de todos. Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado pela confirmação quanto ao pt_PT.

Comment: Eu acho Alô, mundo um pouco estranho em pt_BR também. Geralmente uso Alô quando atendo um telefonema, e normalmente não vejo pessoas se tratarem com "Alô" sem ser por telefone, mas vamos ver o feedback da comunidade para ver se é um problema regional.

Comment: Se você e as pessoas que lhe são mais próximas preferem "alô" a "olá", isso pode ser um regionalismo. Se fosse para deixar do jeito que se fala onde eu nasci e cresci o anúncio diria "oi, mundo!" (fica até cacofônico, parece "ô imundo!"). Acho que "olá" é a forma mais usada se pensarmos em todos os lugares onde se fala Português.

Comment: Só conheço "alô" em contextos telefônicos, tipo nas comunicações da [Terra com Marte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMHsqrI86K4). Acho que depende se o marciano está telefonando ou se aterrizou aqui no nosso planeta. Parece que a preferência é pela aterrizagem em vez do telefonema. +1 pela pergunta curiosa :)

Comment: Acho que alô se aplicaria também no contexto de uma conversa num terminal. De qualquer forma talvez "alô" seja mais parecido foneticamente com expressão inglesa. Finalmente a língua não é uma "ciência exata", por exemplo, quem é que não canta o parabéns pra você e não fala "nesta data querida"? Pra mim "data querida" é estranho, soaria melhor "data especial", só que não :)

Answer (score 8):

Porque isto seria um problema?

Isto vem do famoso programa inicial que alguém faz quando vai iniciar em alguma tecnologia. Ele é chamado originalmente "Hello World" e que foi consagrado em português como ["Olá Mundo"](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa_Ol%C3%A1_Mundo). Sim, existe versões como "Alô Mundo" mas a minha experiência de brasileiro é o uso do "Olá" na maioria dos exemplos.

O importante é que passou a mensagem. Se alguém não conseguir entender a mensagem, terá dificuldade para se comunicar com coisas mais complexas que vão aparecer no *site*.

"Alo Mundo" não seria bom também já que tem um erro ortográfico.

Comment: Pra mim sempre foi alo mundo, com erro ortográfico ou não :), e sim, sou brasileiro. Talvez seja questão de estado. E não disse que não entendi, só pensei que soaria melhor.

Comment: Sua resposta estaria perfeita não fosse a primeira e última linhas. A primeira porque ninguém disse que seria um problebla. A ultima porque você mesmo disse que "o importante é que passou a mensagem".

Comment: Fora que no site em ingles é um show de erro de sintaxe e ortografico e até hoje nunca vi ninguem falar uma virgula sobre esse tipo de erro.